# Webview Refresh with conditions statement

Tags: android, if-statement, conditional-statements, swipe, swiperefreshlayout

When I refresh it will check if there is a connection, if there is a data connected or not error it will be refreshed and if there is data disconnected or error it will be nothing happen.

**MainActivity.java**

```
Boolean error;
error = false

@TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
                    // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
                    try {
                        mWebView.stopLoading();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    showError();

                    error = true;

                }


                private void showError(){


                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Please check your internet connection.", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                if(!error){
                                    mWebView.reload();
                                } else {
                                    showError();
                                }
                            }
                        });


                    snackbar.show();

                }
            });

@Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        if(!error){
            mWebView.reload();
        } else {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    } //
```

Comment: what actually is the question/problem...?

Comment: How to i know onReceivedError before reload URLs?